# XSRF and SOP, different outcome with apparently similar requests

Tags: cookies, xmlhttprequest, xss, csrf

I'm trying to learn more about XSRF and thus about SOP, I'm reading a lot and I have a more or less clear idea about what should happen and what should not, but I can't figure out why i'm obtaining different result while performing the same thing (I assume) in two different ways.

Same basic scenario of may similar questions, *goodsite.com* and *badsite.com*; badsite would like to make a GET request on goodsite.com using user's cookies.
I was able to make this work in a few different ways, a form with an onload send, a button with with an onclick function, they are all working correctly, the query is issued (and ofc i cannot see the response due to SOP).

However i can't  figure out why this is not working

```
xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", "https://goodsite.com/doStuff");
xhReq.withCredentials=true;
xhReq.send();
```

This code, with the same settings/parameters of all the other working solutions is blocked by my browser with this error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://goodsite.com/doStuff' from origin 'https://badguy.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the javascript CORS policy. Servers send a header to tell browsers "Hey, i don't want anyone outside my white list to send me requests using javascript".

Is a security mechanism to avoid things like read the request cookie headers etc.

You can avoid it using a server. There are some online like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
Just add the url to this link if you are feching some content cross origen.

Extended: https://portswigger.net/web-security/cors